# How to emulate Ajax request using PHP CURL?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, curl

I am getting 400 http_code error when I send a Ajax request with CURL below is my Code.

```
    $header = array(
    "Accept : application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
    "Accept-Encoding : gzip, deflate",
    "Accept-Language : en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Content-Type : application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    "Host : https://some.com",
    "Referer : https://some.com/dashboard/reports",
    "X-Requested-With : XMLHttpRequest"
     );
    $c      = curl_init('https://domain.com/report.php');
    //curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    //curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_url );
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest"));

    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_jar);
    $page     = curl_exec($c);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($c);
```

// I am getting following response after making Curl request

```
Array
(
    [url] => some_url
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 400
    [header_size] => 70
    [request_size] => 935
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.205562
    [namelookup_time] => 0.000132
    [connect_time] => 0.032866
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.170225
    [size_upload] => 272
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 1323
    [download_content_length] => 0
    [upload_content_length] => 272
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.205498
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_ip] => 66.35.58.70
    [primary_port] => 443
    [local_ip] => 198.1.92.85
    [local_port] => 53627
    [redirect_url] => 
)
////
```

Comment: `400` means it's a bad request. Figure out what is bad. Maybe a bad header?

Comment: Yes you are right it's client side error but if I not set header it gives 500 http_code and I have also tried many combination for making header ... :)

Comment: Could you narrow down your problem to a minimal example?

Comment: @cmbarbu now I have narrow my code . Please have a look

Comment: What is your $data_url ?
And i think Host and Referer should be different. Host is the domain you're curling : domain.com

Comment: @tetram $data_url is POST array and I am using the right host and refer but actually it's confidential so I  can't write here.....

Comment: @Halcyon yeah that's really all that can be said here, until Fiaz either shows a Fiddler Proxy log of how the real browser-generated request looks like, or shows us the actual url so we can try ourselves. i recommend everyone vote-to-close this question as "can not reproduce" until more information is provided, because we really can not reproduce this atm.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it would help you but i am able to successfully query SSL site with the following code.
There are several things like user agent, cookiefile, SSL verify, url form encoded for post data and subsequent request should use the same cookie and agent data

```
 $config['useragent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $config['useragent']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://google.com/');
$dir = dirname(__FILE__);
$config['cookie_file'] = $dir."/".md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) . '.txt';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $config['cookie_file']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $config['cookie_file']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
$html=curl_exec($ch);
```

Subsequent call request(note it is using the cookie, useragent generated in first request)

```
$post = 'city_id=3&length-3';
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01'; 
$headers[] = 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5';
$headers[] = 'Content-Length:'.strlen($post);
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8';
$headers[] = 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$link);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $config['useragent']);          
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $config['cookie_file']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $config['cookie_file']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
$linkhtml=curl_exec($ch);
```